# Connection issue with Jenkins slave on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, jenkins

I've set up a Jenkins slave node on a Windows Azure VM. When building on that node the project runs smoothly for about 20-30 minutes after which the connection gets dropped. I've been on the node VM as the connection was dropped and it appears it is losing/resetting the connection to the Jenkins Master( also an Azure VM). Has anyone had similar issues and been able to resolve it? The stack trace is as follows. Any help would be appreciated.

> Progress: |=====================FATAL: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Failed to abort
>   hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Failed to abort
>       at hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException.wrapForRethrow(RequestAbortedException.java:41)
>       at hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException.wrapForRethrow(RequestAbortedException.java:34)
>       at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:174)
>       at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:739)
>       at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:168)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.join(Unknown Source)
>       at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$ProcImpl.join(Launcher.java:951)
>       at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.join(CommandInterpreter.java:137)
>       at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:97)
>       at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
>       at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
>       at 
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:745)
>       at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:198)
>       at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:159)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:518)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1709)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
>
> Caused by: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Failed to abort
>       at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:299)
>       at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:802)
>       at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.terminate(Channel.java:483)
>       at hudson.remoting.AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport$1.terminate(AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport.java:72)
>       at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$NioTransport.abort(NioChannelHub.java:184)
>       at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:563)
>       at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to abort
>       ... 9 more
>
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
>       at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.FifoBuffer$Pointer.receive(FifoBuffer.java:136)
>       at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.FifoBuffer.receive(FifoBuffer.java:306)
>       at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:496)
>       ... 7 more

Answer (score 3):

I am also setting up Jenkins CI in Azure and was getting this same problem. Specifically, I would see this error in the Jenkins slave error log:

```
SEVERE: I/O error in channel channel
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

To work around it, you need to increase the frequency with which the slave pings the master. You can do this by adding the `Dhudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingInterval` system property to your master `jenkins.xml` file.

I modified it to ping every 2 minutes and the channel was able to mantain the connection without dropping it. XML looks like this:

```
<arguments>
  -Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingInterval=2 
  -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle 
  -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" 
  --httpPort=8080
</arguments>
```

For more information you can see [the related ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8990).

Comment: farmas, do you know what's the default ping interval?

Comment: found the default - 5 minutes. Other interesting parameters to play with are: hudson.remoting.Launcher.pingIntervalSec and hudson.remoting.Launcher.pingTimeoutSec. Full list is: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties

Answer (score 2):

If you have a newer version of Jenkins (ours is 1.584), you can go to the nodes configure page for the slave, click on the Advanced button under Launch Method, and add `-Dhudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingInterval=2` to the JVM Options field.

That did the trick for us!