# Jenkins windows slave builds "Failed to abort" error

Tags: windows, macos, jenkins, abort, slave

I currently run Jenkins on a mac and slave out a few jobs to a Windows machine, more and more frequently the Windows builds are failing with the following error:

```
17:53:01 FATAL: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Failed to abort
17:53:01 hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Failed to abort
17:53:01    at hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException.wrapForRethrow(RequestAbortedException.java:41)
17:53:01    at hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException.wrapForRethrow(RequestAbortedException.java:34)
17:53:01    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:174)
17:53:01    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:739)
17:53:01    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:168)
17:53:01    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.join(Unknown Source)
17:53:01    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$ProcImpl.join(Launcher.java:956)
17:53:01    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.join(CommandInterpreter.java:137)
17:53:01    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:97)
17:53:01    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
17:53:01    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
17:53:01    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
17:53:01    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
17:53:01    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
17:53:01    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:535)
17:53:01    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
17:53:01    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
17:53:01    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
17:53:01    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
17:53:01 Caused by: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Failed to abort
17:53:01    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:299)
17:53:01    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:802)
17:53:01    at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.terminate(Channel.java:483)
17:53:01    at hudson.remoting.AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport$1.terminate(    AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport.java:72)
17:53:01    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$NioTransport.abort(NioChannelHub.java:195)
17:53:01    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:581)
17:53:01    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
17:53:01    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
17:53:01    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
17:53:01    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
17:53:01    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
17:53:01    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
17:53:01    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
17:53:01 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to abort
17:53:01    ... 9 more
17:53:01 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Operation timed out
17:53:01    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
17:53:01    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:21)
17:53:01    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:198)
17:53:01    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:171)
17:53:01    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:245)
17:53:01    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.FifoBuffer$Pointer.receive(FifoBuffer.java:136)
17:53:01    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.FifoBuffer.receive(FifoBuffer.java:306)
17:53:01    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:514)
17:53:01    ... 7 more
```

I'm under the impression that this is just due to a network issue causing the slave connection to die but I'm not entirely sure.

Has anyone got any idea or has anyone see this before?

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution [Connection issue with Jenkins slave on Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347077/connection-issue-with-jenkins-slave-on-windows-azure)
@Dr1Ku: To work around it, you need to increase the frequency with which the slave pings the master. You can do this by adding the Dhudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingInterval system property to your master jenkins.xml file.