# Jenkins slaves constantly losing connection

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins (1.599) instance starts up and all slaves (Windows services on Win Server 2012 R2) are reported as online.

After 5 minutes or so, the slaves will go down temporarily.  In the UI they are shown as offline.  However they quickly start up again and are shown as online.

I've tried setting the ping time (Dhudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.pingInterval=-1) without success.

Any additional clues from the log files?

```
Master log
-------------------
Feb 26, 2016 7:11:56 AM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler run
INFO: Accepted connection #72172 from /23.100.39.54:14340
Feb 26, 2016 7:11:56 AM jenkins.slaves.JnlpSlaveHandshake error
WARNING: TCP slave agent connection handler #72172 with /23.100.39.54:14340 is aborted: AZSPDF01 is already connected to this master. Rejecting this connection.
Feb 26, 2016 7:11:56 AM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler run
INFO: Accepted connection #72173 from /23.100.39.54:12537
Feb 26, 2016 7:11:56 AM jenkins.slaves.JnlpSlaveHandshake error
WARNING: TCP slave agent connection handler #72173 with /23.100.39.54:12537 is aborted: AZSPDF01 is already connected to this master. Rejecting this connection.
Feb 26, 2016 7:11:56 AM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler run
INFO: Accepted connection #72174 from /23.100.39.54:12538
Feb 26, 2016 7:11:56 AM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler run
WARNING: Connection #72174 failed
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener$ConnectionHandler.run(TcpSlaveAgentListener.java:150)

Slave log
------------------

Feb 07, 2016 1:32:56 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP2-connect
Feb 07, 2016 1:32:56 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
Feb 07, 2016 1:38:16 PM hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread run
SEVERE: I/O error in channel channel
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.FlightRecorderInputStream.read(FlightRecorderInputStream.java:82)
    at hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readHeader(ChunkedInputStream.java:72)
    at hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readUntilBreak(ChunkedInputStream.java:103)
    at hudson.remoting.ChunkedCommandTransport.readBlock(ChunkedCommandTransport.java:39)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)
```

Comment: Firewall, antivirus tools? Did you checks windows logs?

Answer (score 1):

These problems can be hard to debug. I had a similar one on a Linux master/slave (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14332) and it took me a while to get it stable.
Some places to get you started:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remoting+issue
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24895
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28155
- [Connection issue with Jenkins slave on Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347077/connection-issue-with-jenkins-slave-on-windows-azure)